# Use RSS To Display Blog Post From Another Site

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, rss

I am currently using something like this to pull one article from the RSS feed of another one of my blogs. Both sites are Wordpress on same server (NOT MU) The issue is I'd like to be able to pull the excerpt, post date, category and thesis post image or thumbnail. Right now I can only get the post title and permalink to work. Any attempt to get_content or get_excerpt etc has failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('http://idea-driven.com/feed/');
if(!empty($rss)):
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(1);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use [WP XMLRPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to list posts and cache the results. What you are doing here is a performance nightmare as on each page load you do a request to a remote site that may or may not work.**

*Simple RSS will NOT EVER give you what you need.* And you don't want to scrape your own blog when you can use WP XMLRPC to list posts. It's not an easy feat... but it can help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I appreciate the answer however surely this is not the first request of this type. I really need some A LOT more guidance here. The link you gave provided very little insight. If you or anyone else has a viable solution worked out as a code snippet I'd be appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: @user1447958 No such thing! This is a medium to difficult task and not a copy paste solution. *This will actually require you to **LEARN***. I know, it's a terrible concept in today's codepy-paste mentality but there are also non-copy-paste friendly tasks. This is one of them.